# How to migrate an Oracle database

Tags: database, oracle, migrate

Sorry if my question has already been asked but I couldn't find how to make it.

I created an Oracle database in a server and I would like to generate a script in order to copy it to a different server. I would like to copy everything (tables, data, thriggers, sequences...)

Does anyone have a link on how to do this please ?

Thank you.

Comment: did u atlest google for this?

Comment: If you're using Oracle, you certainly must have a system administrator. Can your system administrator help?

Comment: Yes I have been looking on Google but I couldn't find something as simple as in MySQL for instance where it generates a text file containing the whole queries to create the database elsewhere. Is there something like this in Oracle ?

Comment: SQL Developer has a database export tool which allows you to export all the DDL for a schema, and/or the data, all as SQL scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I googled oracle export and found this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch01.htm

so the binary `exp` is what you are looking for to create a dump

Examples:

`exp username/password`

To invoke Export as SYSDBA, use the following syntax, adding any desired parameters or parameter filenames:

`exp \'username/password AS SYSDBA\'`

Optionally, you could also specify an instance name:

`exp \'username/password@instance AS SYSDBA\'`

After you have copied the export file, on the target server, use `imp` to import the dump.
Here is the documentation for `imp` http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch02.htm#1005452

**EDIT:**
As stated in the comments by Jeffrey Kemp, exp/imp is deprecated with oracle 10:
http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g.php

Comment: exp/imp are deprecated in favour of expdp / impdp. http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g.php

Comment: Thanks for your info. He did not state his oracle version and I have currently none.